# WC small organisms ID?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, limnology

I have reached the end of my Winogradsky Column experiment, but out of interest I have kept them for a little longer. I have noticed small bug- and worm-like organisms appearing in some of my columns. All mud and water was sourced from a nearby pond in Florida. The bug-like organisms are simply swimming/crawling around inside the column, while the worms are sticking up from the mud and wriggling. This pictured column was part of a group kept under a heat lamp.

[image]

[image]

Could anyone please provide an ID for these organisms? I think the worms are bloodworms, but I am not sure and I do not know what the small bug-like organisms could be, either.

Comment: Please always include specimen sizes for [tag:species-identification] questions. Also, each question post should only focus on 1 species. It seems your interest is in the non-worm organisms, so please edit your post to exclude questions about the worms (you may ask about them in a separate post; though, better pictures will likely be needed for ID). In fact, better pictures for this post would also be beneficial for future readers and to ensure the most accurate ID. Finally, you mention "swimming/crawling", which are very different behaviors. Could you specify which you're observing. Thanks.

Comment: Appears single-celled, but they look too big to be any kind of euglena or paramecia that I know. (again, knowing size would be helpful). Body shape doesn't immediately conform to other single-celled organisms I can think of off the top of my head, and they don't look like they're insect larva or crustaceans (e.g. daphnia). Nothing definitive stands out, but I think this is a case of poor quality photo + lacking details. Your post would really benefit from including 1) a zoomed/microscope image and 2) a [gif](https://ezgif.com/video-to-gif) of a video capturing their movement

Comment: the other thing that comes to mind are certain snail larvae, but again I'm not seeing detail to convince me that's what you have. More generally, do you see any appendages of any kind? (I don't in your images). Again, more detail would be great. Thanks

Comment: Alright, thank you for the advice! I unfortunately do not have a microscope but I will try to get clearer pictures with size.